# Django - Error when adding two foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

Good afternoon.

I am trying to build a football / soccer calculator in Django.

For that, i created two Models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    teamName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.teamName

class Match(models.Model):
    homeTeam = models.ManyToManyField(Team, related_name="homeTeam")
    # awayTeam = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="awayTeam")
```

As you can see, i tried to put two models.Foreign key, to the Team Model, since that only two teams play on a match.

If i have two

```
homeTeam = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="homeTeam")
awayTeam = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="awayTeam")
```

I cannot add nor even see the matches page in the admin log. What's my code problem?

Thank you in advance for your help :).

Sam!

Comment: I guess you want to put these foreign keys on `Match`?

Comment: Having two ForeignKey fields to the same model works fine (as long as you have distinct related names, which is the case here - even if your related names are wrong, remember these will be the names of the accessors in the _other_ side of the relationship). Do you have any error message in your dev server's output ?

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers

I had one error message. I tried to update database with SyncDB but didn't work.

Then i found the "unpowered" side of Syncdb, and discovered that i had to remove database, and then generate it again. 

SyncDB doesn't alter tables, so the app didn't look at the schema on an updated version :S.

But it's fixed now, thanks ;)

Comment: @Sammy : you may want to start using south for your schema / data migrations. http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/